# Build and link multiple NDK libraries using gradle

Tags: android-ndk, gradle

I have an Android project that links together a bunch of sources into a single monolithic JNI library. I would like to split this single library out into multiple smaller libraries with some dependencies between them. How can I achieve this with the new gradle build system?

Comment: Hello, I have the exact same concern, have you found a way to achieve this? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the standalone android native plugin from the [experimental gradle plugin family](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental). The new plugins are based on the [gradle component approach towards modeling builds](http://gradle.org/the-new-gradle-model/). There are [many advantages to using the new system](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/software_model.html).

For example:

```
root
+ lib -> 'com.android.model.native'
+ lub -> 'com.android.model.native'
+ aar -> 'com.android.model.library'
+ app -> 'com.android.model.application'
```

**build.gradle**

```
configure([project(':lib'), project(':lub'), project(':aar'), project(':app')]) {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5'
        }
    }
}
```

**lib/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.native"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
    ndk {
        moduleName "foo"
    }
    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "src/main/headers"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**lub/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.native"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
    ndk {
        moduleName "bar"
    }
    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "include"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**aar/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.library"

model {
    android {
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        compileSdkVersion 23
    ndk {
        moduleName "aggregate-jni"
        stl "stlport_shared" // using cpp?
    }
    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    project ":lib"
                    project ":lub"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        compileSdkVersion 23 

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':aar')
}
```

If linkage is dynamic (default for ndk), the aar will contain:

```
libfoo.so libbar.so libaggregate-jni.so libstlport.so
```

and your mirror java classes. You can simply

```
System.load("aggregate-jni");
```

in your java classes and referenced libraries will load too. If linkage is static, you'll end up with a single `libaggregate-jni.so` anyway. Note that it's bad to link a bunch of things statically against the stl as you will [end up with multiple copies of the stl in your binary](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262195/whats-wrong-with-statically-linking-the-stl-into-multiple-shared-libraries). This can really mess things up.

Note that the default [`gcc` toolchain is now deprecated](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/CHANGELOG.md). It's probably best to use:

```
model {
    android {
        ndk {
            toolchain 'clang'
            stl 'c++_shared'
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you absolutely don't need an aar, I simply included it for completeness. The app project can depend directly on standalone native lib projects as the application plugin fully support the ndk, too.

Comment: My experience in c is limited, so excuse a couple ignorant questions:
1) What is 'lub'?
2) The exported headers field is just the location of the c header files, nothing special?  Same thing we'd feed to LOCAL_C_INCLUDES before?

Comment: @Anthony re #2 yes. It's the location of headers which constitute the public API of the component you are linking against. Other gradle projects need to know where to find headers for components they depend upon.

Comment: Have you successfully created multiple dependencies?
                `dependencies {
                    project ":lib"
                    project ":lub"
                }`
only grabs the first project.  If I swap them the missing dependencies switch, but it doesn't seem to add both.

Comment: @Anthony multiple dependencies work for me. What aspect isn't working for you?

Comment: Basically whichever dependency comes second leads to a ton of "undefined reference" related to the second dependency.  If I swap the order of the dependencies then I get the same thing in the other library.  I started a question for it, we could continue discussion there so credit can be given if we figure it out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964577/android-native-dependencies