# Android native dependencies

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

Supposedly we can now define dependencies on native-only libraries, but I'm having an issue adding multiple dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 11
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

        sources {
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        project ":libraw"
                        project ":libjpeg"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "rawprocessor"
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            ldLibs.add("log")
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }
    }
}
```

The two libraries are `com.android.model.native` and they generate an .so properly.

Headers are loaded from foo, but not bar.  If I swap the lines they'll load from bar but not foo.  Is there a way to load multiple dependencies?

**Update** (Actual error messages, complete build.gradle added)

```
undefined reference to 'jpeg_std_error'
undefined reference to 'jpeg_CreateDecompress' 
undefined reference to 'jpeg_mem_src'
```

These continue for any reference to libjpeg in the aggregate library.  If I swap libjpeg to be first I get the same undefined reference to any call in the other library.

```
undefined reference to `open_file(char const*, long long)'
undefined reference to `recycle()'
```

**Update 2**

I just noticed that when I add the aggregate library module (the above build.gradle), the build process does not build the second library.  If I comment out that library it builds both native-only libraries.  I'm now starting to wonder if there's some issue due to the fact that `libraw` also depends on `libjpeg`.

Comment: Maybe post some error output and a little more context?

Comment: Updated, figured I was just missing some means to insert an array so I was overly brief.

Comment: Are your projects actually called `libraw` and `libjpeg` or just `raw` and `jpeg`?

Comment: Yes, those are the names of the modules, exactly as defined in settings.gradle.

Comment: Needed to work on another pc today and decided to just exhaustively recreate the project and I successfully built.  Obviously a typo somewhere,  I'll update when I have a chance to diff the two installs.

Comment: How have you achieved configuring separate native libraries that generate separate .so archives?

Comment: Negative, spent another day on it then moved on...tried tons of things, static/shared, simplified as much as I could.  It might be worthwhile building a boilerplate project to see if it can work at all.